# FTP file transfer access denied

Tags: ftp

I installed Windows Server 2008 on my VMWare machine. In Windows Server 2008, I installed FTP and ran it. I also turn off all firewalls. However, from my main machine, I could not send a text file and got this errors:

200 PORT command successful. 
550 file.txt: Access is denied.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got this error message when trying to upload a file to the server, it is possible that you did not enable write permissions for the folder that you are uploading to.

Comment: Yes, it's the problem. Enabling write permissions fixes the issue